# Problem with Ubuntu 20.04 loading Logitech 920 Pro Webcam via guvcview or Cheese

Tags: 20.04, webcam

I successfully used Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to operate my Logitech C920 Pro webcam through the use of Guvcview. Recently upgraded my computer to Ubuntu 20.04.  Now, Guvcview recognizes the webcam, but I cannot capture and stop the basic video functions like before.  Suggestions are welcomed.